# Expressions for moments of sample cumulants?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, symbolic, distributions

I sample $n$ points from standard normal and need the mean and variance of 3rd and 4th sample cumulants.

@JimB [suggested](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/486066/asymptotic-distribution-of-3rd-and-4th-sample-cumulants?noredirect=1#comment897597_486066) that variance of 4th sample cumulant is given by the expression below. This seems like a very algebraically nice expression, is there way to derive/verify it with the help of Mathematica?

$$
\frac {24(n-1)((n-6)n+24)}{n^4}
$$

**Edit, Sep 5**

The following gives a way to verify the formula for a fixed $n$, but not helpful for deriving the formula in terms of $n$

```
n = 5;
Clear[v];
rvec = Array[v, n];
sampleDist = ProductDistribution @@ Table[NormalDistribution[], n];
cumulantDist = 
  TransformedDistribution[Cumulant[rvec, 4], 
   rvec \[Distributed] sampleDist];
Variance[cumulantDist] == (24 (n - 1) ((n - 6) n + 24))/n^4
```

Comment: Have a look at the mathstatica package, they also have a free book http://www.mathstatica.com/book/bookcontents.html

Comment: @yarchik thanks for the pointer, it seems this issue is discussed in Section 7.3 "moments of moments". I actually bought 1.0 version of their package a while back, good to see they are still maintaining it

Answer (score 3):

Here is a solution which is completely general, and works for any random variable whose moments exist. The standard Normal is then just a special and simple case.

The OP is interested in the $3^\text{rd}$ and $4^\text{th}$ sample cumulants (a type of sample moment, similar to sample central moments). The *lingua franca* for working with sample moments, and moments of sample moments, is to structure everything in terms of power sum notation,  $s_r = \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^r$.

The *mathStatica* package for *Mathematica* has a function to express sample cumulants into power sum notation. Here is the $4^\text{th}$ sample cumulant, expressed in terms of power sums:

[image]

This statistic is a random variable, and the OP wishes to find some moments of it.

The mean of k4 is simply the $1^\text{st}$ Raw Moment of k4:

[image]

The variance of k4 is the $2^\text{nd}$ Central Moment of k4:

[image]

... where the solution is expressed in terms of the central moments $\mu_i$ of the population of the parent random variable $X$.

Note that this solution is completely general, and holds for any random variable whose moments exist.

### The standard Normal case

In the simple standard Normal case $X \sim N(0,1)$, the first 8 central moments $\mu_r$ of the population are:

[image]

Substituting these values into the solutions above yields the mean of k4 as:

[image]

and the variance of k4 as:

[image]

All done.

Answer (score 2):

This is similar approach using `FindSequenceFunction` using the sample cumulant definition that *Mathematica* uses.  (That sample cumulant definition is not always unbiased for the population cumulant.)

First define a function that finds the variance for the k-th cumulant for a sample size of $n$ from a Normal[0,1] distribution.

```
variance[k_, n_] := Module[{e1, e2, expectations},
  (* Finds variance of k-th cumulant for a sample of size n from a Normal[0,1] distribution *)
  (* Raw moments of a Normal[0,1] *)
  expectations = Table[x[i_]^i -> Expectation[z^i, z \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[0, 1]], 
    {i, 2 k, 1, -1}];
  (* Expectation of sample cumulant *)
  e1 = (Cumulant[Table[x[i], {i, n}], k] // Expand) /. expectations;
  (* Expecation of square of sample cumlant *)
  e2 = (Cumulant[Table[x[i], {i, n}], k]^2 // Expand) /. expectations;
  e2 - e1^2]
```

Now find the variance for the 3rd and 4th cumulants:

```
v3 = Table[{n, variance[3, n]}, {n, 2, 10}];
FindSequenceFunction[v3, n] // FullSimplify
```

$$\frac{6 (n-2) (n-1)}{n^3}$$

```
v4 = Table[{n, variance[4, n]}, {n, 2, 10}];
FindSequenceFunction[v4, n] // FullSimplify
```

$$\frac{24 (n-1) ((n-6) n+24)}{n^4}$$

Answer (score 2):

*mathStatica* (for me) has the more straightforward way to getting what you asked (as @wolfies has demonstrated).  Here is how to accomplish that in a somewhat similar fashion in *Mathematica*.

```
(* Sample statistic *)
(k4 = MomentConvert[Cumulant[4], "SampleEstimator"] /. PowerSymmetricPolynomial[0] -> n) // TraditionalForm
```

[image: Sample estimator for the 4th cumulant]

```
(* Mean of sample statistic *)
(meank4 = MomentConvert[k4, "CentralMoment"] /. PowerSymmetricPolynomial[0] -> n // FullSimplify) // TraditionalForm
```

[image: Mean of sample statistic]

```
(* Variance of sample statistic *)
(vark4 = MomentConvert[k4^2 - meank4^2, "CentralMoment"] /. PowerSymmetricPolynomial[0] -> n // Simplify) // TraditionalForm
```

[image: Variance of sample 4th cumulant]

These can be simplified under the assumption of random samples from a Normal(0,1) distribution:

```
meank4 /. CentralMoment[i_] -> CentralMoment[NormalDistribution[0, 1], i] // FullSimplify
```

[image: Mean under N(0,1)]

```
vark4 /. CentralMoment[i_] -> CentralMoment[NormalDistribution[0, 1], i] // FullSimplify
```

[image: Variance under N(0,1)]

Answer (score 1):

An idea from JimB was to use `FindSequenceFunction`

```
getExpr[n_] := Module[{v},
  rvec = Array[v, n];
  sampleDist = ProductDistribution @@ Table[NormalDistribution[], n]; 
  cumulantDist = 
   TransformedDistribution[Cumulant[rvec, 4], 
    rvec \[Distributed] sampleDist]; Variance[cumulantDist]
  ];
values = Table[{n, getExpr[n]}, {n, 1, 9}];
FindSequenceFunction[values] (* (24 (-24 + 30 #1 - 7 #1^2 + #1^3))/#1^4 & *)
```

Answer (score 1):

An alternative way to use `MomentConvert` + `MomentEvaluate`:

### $\kappa _3$

---

***Mean***

```
μκ3 = FullSimplify @ 
   MomentConvert[Cumulant[3], {"SampleEstimator", n}, {"CentralMoment", n}];

TraditionalForm @ μκ3
```

[image]

```
MomentEvaluate[μκ3, NormalDistribution[]]
```

> ```
> 0
> ```

---

***Variance***

```
σκ3 = FullSimplify[
   MomentConvert[Cumulant[3]^2, {"SampleEstimator", n}, {"CentralMoment", n}] - μκ3^2];

TraditionalForm @ σκ3
```

[image]

```
MomentEvaluate[σκ3, NormalDistribution[]]
```

[image]

---

---

### $\kappa _4$

---

***Mean***

```
μκ4 = FullSimplify @ 
   MomentConvert[Cumulant[4], {"SampleEstimator", n}, {"CentralMoment", n}];

TraditionalForm @ μκ4
```

[image]

```
MomentEvaluate[μκ4, NormalDistribution[]]
```

[image]

---

***Variance***

```
σκ4 = FullSimplify[
   MomentConvert[Cumulant[4]^2, {"SampleEstimator", n}, {"CentralMoment", n}] - μκ4^2];

TraditionalForm @ σκ4
```

[image]

```
MomentEvaluate[σκ4, NormalDistribution[]]
```

[image]

---